# canot find the module 'react' in nexjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have been setting up redux on my next.js application but I am continuously getting this error. I'm not able to detect from where it's coming and for what reason. I'm using next.js 13 version and app directory is not enabled. Here is below screenshot and code which I wrote in order to add redux in my application.

[image]

_app.tsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Layout from "components/Layout/Layout";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
// import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import store from "store/store";
import React from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* <PersistGate loading={<>Loading...</>} persistor={persistor}> */}
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      {/* </PersistGate> */}
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "reducers/root-reducer";
// import rootReducer from "reducers/root-reducer";
// import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
// import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
// import React from "react";

// const persistConfig = { key: "root", storage };

// const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
// export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

The commented code you see is what I made in order to check if the error gets out but its still there. What is the issue?

Comment: You need to import react in order for the react-redux Provider to work properly. To do this, add the following line at the top of your file: 

import React from 'react';

Comment: have you checked your package.json or reinstall packages.